# "Single-row subquery returns more than one row" in Update statement

Tags: oracle, sql-update, ora-01427

I've been struggling for a couple of days to work out how to make my `update` statement work.
The `select` statement appears to work as expected, but when I try to update my column values I get an `ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row` error.

Here's the code:

```
UPDATE tbl_metrics
SET act_end_time = (WITH base
AS (SELECT caseid, entry_timestamp
       FROM activity
      WHERE act_id IN (100, 700, 300)
      )  
SELECT t1.entry_timestamp
FROM base t1, tbl_metrics t2
WHERE t1.caseid = t2.caseid
AND t2.act_start_time < (SELECT MIN(t1.entry_timestamp) FROM base t1 WHERE t1.caseid = t2.caseid))
```

The idea is that the `tbl_metrics.act_end_time` column is updated with the lowest `entry_timestamp` value from `activity` table where `activity.caseid=tbl_metrics.caseid` and `activity.entry_timestamp>tbl_metrics.act_start_time` and the `activity.act_id` is 100, 700, or 300.

Comment: Might want to start with a where on the update

Comment: @Patrick Could you please be more specific? I've been stuffing around with this for so long I'm just totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_metrics t2
SET act_end_time = 
    (SELECT MIN(t1.entry_timestamp) 
    FROM activity t1 
    WHERE act_id IN (100, 700, 300)
        AND t1.entry_timestamp > t2.act_start_time
        AND t1.caseid = t2.caseid)
```

Comment: That worked well, thank. Nice and simple. Performance was better than I thought, didn't need the `with` section to stop having to go to `activity` table to just grab the set of `act_id`'s